# Can't bring windows forward in Windows 8 unless I click on icon in taskbar

Tags: windows-8, window-manager

OK, I have this weird problem with my brand new Windows 8 install. Sometimes, moving my mouse to a program doesn't bring it forward. The only way to get to the program is then to click on the icon up in the taskbar. This is really annoying. Anyone heard of this or know what to do about it?

Comment: You say moving a mouse to the program, I assume you are clicking on the program's window somewhere. Does this only happen for specific programs or all?

Comment: Hmm. Ok, so I just checked, and it appears to be only happening with Maxthon Cloud Browser (v4.0.6.2000). All other programs are OK. Say I am in Maxthon with 6 tabs open, then open a small Notepad window in front of it. With the focus on this Notepad window, I can't click into Maxthon (bring it forward) without first clicking on its icon up in the taskbar first.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Maxthon.

Comment: True. I asked at the Maxthon forum: http://forum.maxthon.com/thread-2118-1-1.html